# PHP $_POST not working for HTML form

Tags: php, html

I am a beginner in php. I am trying to create a simple form for my site but it doesn't seem to work.

This is my php test code

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($_GET);
var_dump($_REQUEST);
?>
```

Here is my HTML code

```
<form method="post" action="emailForm.php"  name="contactForm">
  <input id="nameInput" type="text" placeholder="YOUR NAME" name="nameInput"/>
  <input id="emailInput" type="email" placeholder="YOUR EMAIL" name="emailInput"/>
  <textarea id="messageInput" placeholder="MESSAGE GOES HERE" name="messageInput"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT>>" class="wordButton" id="submitButton">
</form>
```

No matter what I enter into the text fields for the form for the html page I am always getting the same results.

This is what's printed:

```
array (size=3)
  'nameInput' => string '' (length=0)
  'emailInput' => string '' (length=0)
  'messageInput' => string '' (length=0)

array (size=0)
  empty

array (size=3)
  'nameInput' => string '' (length=0)
  'emailInput' => string '' (length=0)
  'messageInput' => string '' (length=0)
```

Why is it returning empty strings when I have entered value into it?

Comment: FYI : If you not sure for Get or Post, use $_REQUEST[' ']; but you define method post then you can use $_POST[' '];

Comment: have you tried printing $_POST to verify that what you are getting in it ?

Comment: you can check variable is set by checking thisisset($_POST['emailInput']) meke sure your form is run perfectly.

Comment: print_r($_POST) and see what are you receiving in post request

Comment: If I print_r($_POST) I get this: "Array ( [nameInput] => [emailInput] => [messageInput] => ) 1" With all the form values set to "test" and then print_r($_POST['nameInput']) I get just: "1"

Comment: Are you asking how to submit data and retrieve it in $_POST?

Comment: Well whatever I put in the text box of my html, and use $_POST like $_POST['nameInput'] to retrieve it, it's just a null string.

Comment: I always include this: `if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST' ) die('Not POST');`

Answer (score 0):

It should work only when the form data is posted. Try with -

```
<?php 
$errors = '';
if (!empty($_POST['nameInput']) || !empty($_POST['emailInput']) || !empty($_POST['messageInput'])) {
    $name = $_POST['nameInput']; 
    $email_address = $_POST['emailInput']; 
    $message = $_POST['messageInput']; 
    if(!filter_var($email_address, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $errors .= "\n Error: Invalid email address $email_address. name is:".$name."- $message";
    }  
}


?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"> 
<html>
<head>
    <title>Message Submitted</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
echo $errors;
?>


</body>
</html>
```

And there should be a check for valid email.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP Version is Older than php 4.1.0 ! 
Update Your PHP.